# lein ring server giving Compiler exception

Tags: clojure, leiningen, ring

I am reading "Living Clojure" (2014) book and it has a project called `cheshire-cat`. My `project.clj` file is following:

```
(defproject cheshire-cat "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [compojure "1.3.1"]
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.1.2"]
                 [ring/ring-json "0.3.1"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2371"]
                 [cljs-http "0.1.18"]
                 [org.clojure/core.async "0.1.346.0-17112a-alpha"]
                 [enfocus "2.1.0"]
                 [javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api "2.3.1"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.13"]
            [lein-cljsbuild "1.0.3"]]
  :ring {:handler cheshire-cat.core.handler/app}
  :profiles
  {:dev {:dependencies [[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]
                        [ring-mock "0.1.5"]]}}
  :cljsbuild {
    :builds [{
      :source-paths ["src-cljs"]
      :compiler {
        :output-to "resources/public/main.js"
        :optimizations :whitespace
        :pretty-print true}}]})
```

When I try to start the ring server with `$lein ring server` command, it gives the compiler exception error: https://pastebin.com/xJmVrJqa

How to make the ring server command work without error?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are trying to use an **eight year old** example with **eight year old** versions of all the dependencies. I'm not surprised it doesn't work, but I am *amazed* that it got as close as it did.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're hitting this issue: https://github.com/metosin/compojure-api/issues/426

Which apparently got fixed by this commit: https://github.com/metosin/compojure-api-template/pull/7/files

So I'd try updating the `org.clojure/clojure` version in `project.clj`. If that doesn't work, try other dependencies as well. Specifically `compojure` and `lein-ring`. But before updating any dependency, check its changelog to see if you also have to modify the code somewhat to accommodate the newer version.

Usually, such things don't happen in the Clojure world. But in this case, judging by that commit description, it seems like Leiningen has broken some backward compatibility at some point.